# JFileChooser on Windows - exception when only space is entered

Tags: java, swing, java-11

#### Description

A `JFileChooser` is used in a Java Swing application. Users are able to enter any filename permitted by the operating system, but from time to time they will enter erroneous filenames, such as names including invalid characters.

If a user enters a name ending with a space, such as

- `SomeName`

an error message is shown. This is done by overriding `JFileChooser#approveSelection`, matching the filename to an undesired regex and then displaying an error dialog.

**However when the user enters only a space, then an exception is thrown:**

```
2022-10-18 12:34:54 SEVERE (CustomExceptionHandler::uncaughtException) Uncaught exception: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 22: C:\X\Y\Z\  on [AWT-EventQueue-0]
Exception Stacktrace:
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 22: C:\X\Y\Z\ 
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:191)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.getShellFolder(ShellFolder.java:247)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI.changeDirectory(BasicFileChooserUI.java:1353)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI$ApproveSelectionAction.actionPerformed(BasicFileChooserUI.java:1142)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1070)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFileChooser.showDialog(JFileChooser.java:769)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFileChooser.showSaveDialog(JFileChooser.java:691)
    at core.RetainerExportController.exportRetainer(RetainerExportController.java:156)
    at core.RetainerExportController.lambda$1(RetainerExportController.java:64)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

This exception keeps popping up in our error logs, because while users are instructed not to enter spaces as filenames, they still will from time to time.

#### Investigation

After looking into this, the problem appears to be coming from the `BasicFileChooserUI`. There is a filter for missing or empty strings in the class:

```
if (filename == null || filename.length() == 0) {
                // no file selected, multiple selection off, therefore cancel the approve action
                resetGlobFilter();
                return;
}
```

However there is no filter for a blank filename. So this name is not filtered by `BasicFileChooserUI`, but it is recognized to be ending on a space by the `WindowsPathParser`, which leads to the error.

There is more odd behavior as well. For example entering a name consisting purely of forbidden characters, such as

- `???`

results in just nothing happening, *i.e.*

- No exception is thrown
- `JFileChooser#approveSelection` is also never reached

#### How to solve?

It is not clear how to solve it, because all of the erroneous behavior occurs in internal Swing and `sun.nio.fs` code. *E.g.* there are regex filters in our `JFileChooser` implementation, which trigger upon `approveSelection` and check for names consisting of spaces and invalid characters - however `approveSelection` is never called in this scenario. It is called if `WindowsPathParser#parse` and `WindowsPathParser#normalize` are passed, but otherwise the error handling is useless, because some weird internal error handling is done internally beforehand.

I've looked into extending the `WindowsFileChooserUI` or the `BasicFileChooserUI`, but not only would that introduce unnecessary explicit dependencies on the desktop package for the latter case, but it is (as far as I see) not possible to do, at least with anything close to clean software design, because both of those classes use private members that are crucial to the problem at hand. E.g. `WindowsFileChooserUI` holds the `JTextField` which handles the user input as a private member and sets it up and uses it in the same method, so accessing it and even modifying it in any class attempting to extend `WindowsFileChooserUI` is going to be a problem.

**Long story short - how do I prevent an `InvalidPathException` from being thrown, when users open the `JFileChooser` dialog and enter only a space?**

#### Notes

Because internal APIs are affected the used JDK may be relevant: `11.0.14_9`

The dialog creation itself is not spectacular, it is created thusly:

```
JFileChooser dialog = new CustomFileChooser( file );
dialog.setDialogType( JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG );
dialog.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed( false );
```

The only methods that are overridden by `CustomFileChooser` are

- `createDialog`
- `approveSelection`

#### Minimal reproducible example

Because an example has been requested, the error can be reproduced as follows:

1. Set up a swing application (e.g. in Eclipse)
2. Create a `JFileChooser` dialog as such:

```
JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser( file );
dialog.setDialogType( JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG );
dialog.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed( false );
```

3. Run the application, make sure the dialog creation is triggered
4. In the dialog enter a space as filename:
5. Confirm
6. An `InvalidPathException` is thrown

Note that this error requires the JVM being run on Windows and my tests happened on Java 11.

Comment: It's not clear to me. Have you written a class that extends `JFileChooser`? Would you consider writing your own _file chooser_ component, i.e. one that does **not** extend `JFileChooser` (but maybe has a member variable of type `JFileChooser`)?

Comment: I am using a custom `JFileChooser` - `CustomFileChooser`, yes. However, the behavior is the same for a standard file chooser. I just created one via `JFileChooser saveDialog = new JFileChooser( file );` and the behavior when a user enters a space as a filename is exactly the same. You can test this.

Comment: We could test this if you had modified your question to include the [mre] you tested with.

Comment: I did provide a minimal reproducible example, which is the codeblock in the section **Notes**.

Comment: The minimal reproducible example has been extended to comply. It includes steps to follow and should be enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: Seems like this bug is already reported as [JDK-8196673](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8196673).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I have had a look at this bug reported, but was not yet convinced enough, that the issue is exactly the same (though it might be). The reason is, the reproducible example in the bug report is handled correctly in Java 11, because the the string `testspace ` will not cause an exception in the `WindowsPathParser` and so can be handled in `JFileChooser#approveSelection`. Still I agree, these seem to be related.

Comment: *I did provide a minimal reproducible example* - That is not an [mre]. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test the code. We should NOT have to create the frame or main() method or add import statements to execute the code. The easier it is for us to test, the more likely we are to test/help.

Comment: The ability to simply copy+paste is not required by the [mre guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I would suggest it is implied. Your choice on how helpful you want to be.  *How to solve?* - a workaround could be to add a `FocusListener` to the text field and do a `trim()` on the text in the text field on `focusLost`. Or you could add a DocumentFilter to the text field to prevent insertion of spaces anywhere. I don't have an MRE to work with, so I can't test the suggestion.

Comment: That’s a though issue. As far as I can see, it’s possible to intercept at the right place using the `FileSystemView` API, but the entire file chooser implementation seems to have no notion of the idea that a path or file name could be invalid (in fact, `java.io.File` doesn’t care for the syntax either). So what to do after detecting the invalid path at the interception point?

Comment: @camickr I disagree on the imports part - an IDE usually can add the imports - if there is no ambiguity (`java.awt.List` and `java.util.List` is such an ambiguity, but I'd go with the util one)

Comment: @Koenigsberg Try it with a single space.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn On Windows 11 in combination with Java `11.0.14_9` a single space input causes the exception to be thrown on my machine. The exception is triggered by the last `if` condition in `WindowsPathParser#normalize`.

Comment: @Holger I am thinking the same. What I found interesting is the distinct behavior for these strings: `abc[space]` versus `[space]`. Both end in a space, so for both `if (lastC == ' ')` results in calling `throw new InvalidPathException`. Only for `abc[space]` this results in correct error handling, while for `[space]` the result is an unhandled exception. The difference is, that for `[space]` the exception ends up being handled in `pumpOneEventForFilters` on the EDT, so there is some distinction in the way these inputs are processed internally.

Comment: @Holger Ah I was too late, I see you posted a response. Will check it out. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Koenigsberg note that I posted an answer which tries to explain it. It boils down to whether `java.io.File` thinks that this invalid path is a directory or not.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn *an IDE usually can add the imports* - you assume people use an IDE. The point of an MRE is to make it easy for everybody. If the OP has already created the MRE, then the imports have already been included, so the OP just need to company the entire class.

Comment: Minimal. Not everyone has a JDK, so should OP also include one?

Comment: @camickr This also doesn't seem to bother you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74066202/gui-jtable-change-borders-to-text/74072551#74072551), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74068743/customize-jfilechooser-vertical-scrollbar/74070636#74070636) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756115/incrementing-a-value-in-java-table-doesnt-work-after-one-record/73756711#73756711).

Comment: @camickr What are you even talking about. There is one useful answer, and it is **not** a proper MRE according to your standards, as it cannot simply be copypasted and be ready to run, but requires not only imports, but a framework being set up around it to compile and execute. I find it hard to believe that your comments in this section and the derisive tone you took since your first comment can be interpreted as anything other than toxicity under the guise of helpfulness.

Comment: @camickr I was responding to the sentiment, *The people that took the time to provide answers took the time to post a better MRE*.

Comment: @camickr Furthermore, I have no interest in engaging in quote wars with you. Your help has been noted. We will keep disagreeing on certain aspects of it. There is no further value to this discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While older file chooser versions stripped spaces from entered file names, they never cared about the validity of the names beyond spaces. E.g. entering something like `\<\>\"` gets accepted. Invalid path names didn’t cause exceptions, because `java.io.File` doesn’t check the syntax either.

In newer versions, the NIO `FileSystem` API is used at some places and the space is not always stripped. The specific exception occurs because `new File(" ").getAbsoluteFile().isDirectory()` evaluates to `true` for some reason (while `new File(" ").isDirectory()` doesn’t), so the file chooser tries to change the directory to the invalid path, instead of invoking `approveSelection()` which the application could override.

Since file chooser’s code can’t cope with exceptions for invalid files, I made this workaround which uses a special `File` subclass which reports not to be a directory and can be detected at `approveSelection()`:

```java
public class FileChooserTest {
    static final class Invalid extends File {
        final String originalName;
        public Invalid(String pathname) {
            super(pathname);
            originalName = pathname;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDirectory() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return originalName;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        if(!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(FileChooserTest::main);
            return;
        }
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser() {
            @Override
            public void approveSelection() {
                if(getSelectedFile() instanceof Invalid) {
                    setSelectedFile(null);
                    return;
                }
                super.approveSelection();
            }
        };
        fc.setFileSystemView(new FileSystemView() {
            @Override
            public File createFileObject(String path) {
                try {
                    Paths.get(path);
                } catch(InvalidPathException ex) {
                    return new Invalid(path);
                }
                return super.createFileObject(path);
            }

            @Override
            public File createFileObject(File dir, String filename) {
                try {
                    Paths.get(filename);
                } catch(InvalidPathException ex) {
                    return new Invalid(filename);
                }
                return super.createFileObject(dir, filename);
            }

            @Override
            public File createNewFolder(File containingDir) throws IOException {
                return FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().createNewFolder(containingDir);
            }
        });
        if(fc.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println(fc.getSelectedFile());
        }
        else System.out.println("Not approved");
    }
}
```

This does not only eliminate the exception but also prevents invalid files from getting approved. Of course, it could be improved, e.g. by providing feedback to the user. But it would be better if bugs like [`JDK-8196673`](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8196673) get fixed anyway.

---

Note: the reason why names containing `*` or `?` are not rejected, is that they are converted to a file name filter. So when you enter, e.g. `*.txt`, it should show up in the filter combobox.

Comment: I will test your solution tomorrow and report results. At first glance I am not yet free of scepticism, because an invalid input `[space]` is handled by recognizing whether a `File` produced from this input is an instance of `Invalid` in `approveSelection`, however my observations have shown so far, that the `InvalidPathException` is triggered before any call to `approveSelection` is made. Will look further into your code tomorrow, thank you for your efforts!

Comment: ...Unless of course this prevents the exception from being thrown in the first place. In any case, I will post updates.

Comment: The crucial part is that the `createFileObject` methods check the validity.

Comment: The solution is brilliant. The idea to leverage `FileSystemView` is great. I modified some parts, *e.g.* holding the filename as member and using reflection to check for `Invalid` may not be necessary to achieve the desired result, so a `JFileChooser` abstraction is not needed. The core concept, however, works perfectly. Answer is accepted, kudos.

Comment: I stored the original name because the chooser resets the text field to the result of `getName()`. That’s only relevant if the invalid text contains a backslash. There’s no Reflection involved. If you mean the `instanceof` test, it’s not strictly necessary. You could repeat the validity test instead. In case of a load dialog you could also use `exists()`. Generally, the code meant as a starting point or sketch, as already mentioned in the answer. So yes, adapt it to your needs as you like…

Comment: I did mean the `instanceof` test, yes. Essentially the overridden `isDirectory` causes the occurring `InvalidPathException` to be handled correctly within the execution flow of `WindowsPathParser`, so it does not end up as an unhandled exception on the EDT. From this point on it can be handled just like any other input error, because the call to `approveSelection` then does occur, which solves my problem. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could simply remove the leading/trailing spaces from the filename before file chooser processing is invoked:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser( );

        JTextField tf = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JTextField.class, fc).get(0);
        tf.addFocusListener( new FocusAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
            {
                JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();
                tf.setText( tf.getText().trim() );
                System.out.println( tf.getText() );
            }
        });

        tf.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();
                    tf.setText( tf.getText().trim() );
                    System.out.println( tf.getText() );
                }
            }
        });

        fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    }
}
```

The above code requires the [Swing Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class.

Comment: I like how you consider peeking into the AWT hierarchy and grabbing the first `JTextField` you can find as “don't … play with the internals of the file chooser”. I doesn’t work however, when you enter a space and just press enter (which is the most likely scenario, as why should a user switch from keyboard to mouse after entering a name)…

Comment: @Holger, This is a bug. Only solution is to play with internals. My thought was that the FileSystemView might be implemented differently on different platforms so that approach may not be portable.  The concept of "editing the data before processing the data" is a common practice. So, this approach should work on all platforms. Yes, grabbing the first text field plays with the internals but I feel is less intrusive then overriding the behaviour of the `File` and `FileSystemView` classes. Just a thought.  Good point about using the Enter key. Code updated.

Comment: “*This is a bug. Only solution is to play with internals.*” No problem with that. It’s just that your answer starts with “*If you don't want to play with the internals…*” I consider using the `FileSystemView`, i.e. the class specifically designed alter this behavior, less intrusive than assuming a particular component hierarchy. But anyway, let’s agree on that some kind of dealing with internals is necessary for working around the bug.

Answer (score -2):

I extended `JFileChooser` to add a confirmation dialog if the file I wanted to save has the same name as an existing file.  Perhaps you can use this to start a more robust version of `JFileChooser`.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OSFileChooser extends JFileChooser {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void approveSelection() {
        File f = getSelectedFile();
        
        if (f.exists() && getDialogType() == SAVE_DIALOG) {
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, f.getName() + 
                    " exists, overwrite?",
                    "Existing file", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
            switch (result) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                super.approveSelection();
                return;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                return;
            case JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION:
                return;
            case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                cancelSelection();
                return;
            }
        }
        
        super.approveSelection();
    }
    
    @Override
    public File getSelectedFile() {
        File file = super.getSelectedFile();
        
        if (file != null && getDialogType() == SAVE_DIALOG) {
            String extension = getExtension(file);
            if (extension.isEmpty()) {
                FileTypeFilter filter = (FileTypeFilter) getFileFilter();
                if (filter != null) {
                    extension = filter.getExtension();
                    String fileName = file.getPath();
                    fileName += "." + extension;
                    file = new File(fileName);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return file;
    }
    
    public String getExtension(File file) {
        String extension = "";
        String s = file.getName();
        int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

        if (i > 0 && i < (s.length() - 1)) {
            extension = s.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase();
        }

        return extension;
    }
    
}
```

And the associated `FileTypeFilter` class.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

public class FileTypeFilter extends FileFilter {
    private String extension;
    private String description;
 
    public FileTypeFilter(String description, String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
        this.description = description;
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
        }
        return file.getName().endsWith("." + extension);
    }
 
    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return description + String.format(" (*.%s)", extension);
    }
    
    public String getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you tested your code? I took the time to integrate your classes into the codebase. The exact same error occurs. Try it yourself. Integrate those classes into your codebase, then call the file chooser dialog, enter only a space and confirm - an exception will be thrown. The problem is independent of the `JFileChooser` robustness, it occurs internally in the interactions between `BasicFileChooserUI` and `WindowsFileChooserUI`.

Comment: @Koenigsberg: I said it was a start.  Not a complete solution.  If I can access the file name for a save, so can you.

Comment: The issue here is, that `BasicFileChooserUI` and `WindowsFileChooserUI` interact with the input of the text field before the `JFileChooser` does. So e.g. filtering the selectable files is not relevant, as the text field is affected. Normally `approveSelection` should be the correct entry point to check filename validity, however an exception is thrown before the `JFileChooser` gets to interact with the user input in any meaningful way. This is why I suspect a JDK bug here and disagree with you on the helpfulness of a better `JFileChooser` implementation. See comments by Holger and Johannes.

Comment: @Koenigsberg: Your last comment is an actionable response.  I suppose you'll have to implement your own `FileChooser` from other Swing components.